# No scrolling list of buttons in ScrollView

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I have an interface layout (cleanscreen.kv):

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<CleanScreen>
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb:
                    0.1, 0.3, 0.6
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10
            height: self.minimum_height
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb: 1, 0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            FloatLayout:
                id: box_share
                size_hint_y: None
```

and Python file (cleanscreen.py):

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

try:
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.uix.image import Image
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    from kivy.lang import Builder
except Exception as text_error:
    raise text_error


class CleanScreen(BoxLayout):
    Builder.load_file("cleanscreen.kv")

    def __init__(self, **kvargs):
        super(CleanScreen, self).__init__(**kvargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        self.create_button(self.ids.box_share)

    def create_button(self, box_share):
        top_logo_share = 1.01
        top_button_share = 1.1
        top_label_share = 1.4

        for i in range(50):
            top_logo_share -= .4
            top_button_share -= .4
            top_label_share -= .4

            logo_share = \
                Image(source="data/logo/kivy-icon-48.png",
                      pos_hint={"center_x": .05, "top": top_logo_share},
                      size_hint_y=None, height=25)
            button_share = \
                Button(pos_hint={"x": 0, "top": top_button_share},
                       size_hint_y=None, height=40)
            label_share = \
                Label(text=str(i), pos_hint={"x": 0, "top": top_label_share},
                      size_hint_y=None)

            box_share.add_widget(button_share)
            box_share.add_widget(logo_share)
            box_share.add_widget(label_share)

if __name__ in ["__main__", "__android__"]:
    import kivy
    kivy.require("1.9.1")


    class Test(App):
        def build(self):
            return CleanScreen()


    Test().run()
```

I wanted to get this result:

[image: I wanted to get this result]

Run this script displays the following result here:

[image: But getting here is]

And the list does not scroll buttons. Where I made an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `FloatLayout` in kv file has no height set, therefore gets either the default one. That doesn't matter actually, because you just push widgets into a widget that will do nothing good when it's inside `GridLayout` that is inside `ScrollView`. Nope, there is a better and more reasonable way(*at least how I see it*). :)

Throw away `FloatLayout` from kv file, there's no need for that and use `GridLayout`, because that's the widget that should get bigger(and affect `ScrollView`) when you push widget to in, not the `FloatLayout` and forcing GridLayout to artificially make itself bigger the other way around.

```
ScrollView:
    GridLayout:
        id: box_share
        cols: 1
        size_hint_y: None
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10
        height: self.minimum_height
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 1, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
```

and in the python file use `create_button()` to create a `FloatLayout` which you fill with your widgets. I'm kind of confused of that positioning, so I'm not going to fix that for you, sorry. Don't forget to set the height of `FloatLayout`.

```
def create_button(self, box_share):
    top_logo_share = 1.01
    top_button_share = 1.1
    top_label_share = 1.4

    for i in range(50):
        top_logo_share -= .4
        top_button_share -= .4
        top_label_share -= .4

        logo_share = \
            Image(source="data/logo/kivy-icon-48.png",
                  pos_hint={"center_x": .05, "top": top_logo_share},
                  size_hint_y=None, height=25)
        button_share = \
            Button(pos_hint={"x": 0, "top": top_button_share},
                   size_hint_y=None, height=40)
        label_share = \
            Label(text=str(i), pos_hint={"x": 0, "top": top_label_share},
                  size_hint_y=None)
        fl = FloatLayout(size_hint_y=None, height=25)
        fl.add_widget(button_share)
        fl.add_widget(logo_share)
        fl.add_widget(label_share)
        box_share.add_widget(fl)
```